# iOS App crashes after successful in-app purchase - Swift 3, Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, in-app-purchase

I have created an in-app purchase to remove ads from the app. In my test app it worked fine but now I have added it to the main app it will not work. I can run through the purchase option fine and I get the message saying "you're all set, your purchase was successful" but straight after the app will crash.

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit

class PurchaseViewController: UIViewController, SKPaymentTransactionObserver, SKProductsRequestDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var statusLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    @IBOutlet var restorePurchasesReference: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var removeAdsReference: UIButton!

    var product: SKProduct?
    var productID = "com.joshbury.GTAVCheats.RemoveAds"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        statusLabel.isHidden = true        
        statusLabel.text = "Remove ads to enjoy an ad free experience!"

        activityIndicator.isHidden = true

        disableRestorePurchasesButton()
        disableRemoveAdsButton()

        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)

        getPurchaseInfo()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func getPurchaseInfo() {

        if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {

            let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: NSSet(object: self.productID) as! Set<String>)

            request.delegate = self
            request.start()

            activityIndicator.isHidden = false
            activityIndicator.startAnimating()

        } else {

            statusLabel.isHidden = false
            statusLabel.text = "In app purchase is currently unavailable"

        }

    }

    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {

        var products = response.products

        if (products.count != 0) {

            product = products[0]

            statusLabel.isHidden = false
            statusLabel.text = "Remove ads to enjoy an ad free experience!"

            activityIndicator.isHidden = true
            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()

            enableRestorePurchasesButton()
            enableRemoveAdsButton()

        } else {

            statusLabel.isHidden = false
            statusLabel.text = "Product not found"

        }

        let invalids = response.invalidProductIdentifiers

        for product in invalids {

            print("Invalid Product...\(product)")

            statusLabel.isHidden = false
            statusLabel.text = "Invalid Product"

            activityIndicator.isHidden = true
            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()

        }

    }

    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {

        for transaction in transactions {

            switch transaction.transactionState {

            case SKPaymentTransactionState.purchased:

                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)

                self.removeAds()

                statusLabel.isHidden = false
                statusLabel.text = "Ads were successfully removed!"

                activityIndicator.isHidden = true
                activityIndicator.stopAnimating()

                disableRestorePurchasesButton()
                disableRemoveAdsButton()

            case SKPaymentTransactionState.restored:

                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)

                self.removeAds()

                statusLabel.isHidden = false
                statusLabel.text = "Restore complete, ads were successfully removed!"

                activityIndicator.isHidden = true
                activityIndicator.stopAnimating()

                disableRestorePurchasesButton()
                disableRemoveAdsButton()

            case SKPaymentTransactionState.failed:

                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)

                statusLabel.isHidden = false
                statusLabel.text = "Ads were not removed!"

                activityIndicator.isHidden = true
                activityIndicator.stopAnimating()

            default:

                break

            }

        }

    }

    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError error: Error) {

        statusLabel.isHidden = false
        statusLabel.text = "Restore failed!"

        activityIndicator.isHidden = true
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()

    }

    func removeAds() {

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

        appDelegate.mainViewController!.removeAds()
        appDelegate.playstationViewController!.removeAds()
        appDelegate.xboxViewController!.removeAds()
        appDelegate.pcViewController!.removeAds()
        appDelegate.mapViewController!.removeAds()

        let save = UserDefaults.standard

        save.set(true, forKey: "adsRemoved")
        save.synchronize()

    }

    func disableRestorePurchasesButton() {

        restorePurchasesReference.isEnabled = false
        restorePurchasesReference.setTitleColor(UIColor.init(red: 209/255, green: 209/255, blue: 209/255, alpha: 0.5), for: UIControlState())

    }

    func enableRestorePurchasesButton() {

        restorePurchasesReference.isEnabled = true
        restorePurchasesReference.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControlState())

    }

    func disableRemoveAdsButton() {

        removeAdsReference.isEnabled = false
        removeAdsReference.setTitleColor(UIColor.init(red: 209/255, green: 209/255, blue: 209/255, alpha: 0.5), for: UIControlState())

    }

    func enableRemoveAdsButton() {

        removeAdsReference.isEnabled = true
        removeAdsReference.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControlState())

    }

    @IBAction func restorePurchases(_ sender: Any) {

        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()

        statusLabel.isHidden = true

        activityIndicator.isHidden = false
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(60)) {

            if self.activityIndicator.isAnimating == true {

                self.statusLabel.isHidden = false
                self.statusLabel.text = "Error"

                self.activityIndicator.isHidden = true
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()

            }

        }

    }

    @IBAction func removeAds(_ sender: Any) {

        let payment = SKPayment(product: product!)

        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)

        statusLabel.isHidden = true

        activityIndicator.isHidden = false
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()

    }


}
```

[Aksing to get it again for free Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43Gza.jpg)

[I get this alert, then it crashes Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ty9Vs.jpg)

Comment: Where exactly it's crashing ? Did you try to debug it using break points ? What was the result of that debug ?

Comment: The culprit it is probably removeAds method

Comment: Tip: change all forced unwrap to conditional chaining. `mainViewController?.removeAds()`

Comment: Removed the self.removeAds() line under .purchased and .restored and it now works fine. Will work on a fix for this now. Thanks everyone for your help.